# 3 level navigation mobile menu

Tags: mobile, menu

I have 3 levels in my information architecture for my hamburger mobile menu.

First level: 5 items
Second level: 8 - 10 items in total
Third level: 6 items

Would you use an accordion style or a sequential drill down menu? and why?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an Accordion style menu with all the items placed in a clean manner and i believe the menu would look better if aligned centrally highlighting it and allowing you to display all items without clatter also allowing for use of icons or Illustrations. It will result in a cleaner UI.